# How can I get something just like Z = Y - X? THANKS

Tags: python

Thinking about this scenario: A team leader assign tasks to team members. The tasks span from Monday to Saturday. The team members aren't available all the time. Member a is not free on 1,3 and b isn't on 1,5 and c isn't on 3,… The schedule of members is stored in database, and I will get it using SQLAlchemy. session.query(name, free_date)

Query X contains members and the days that he is not free

```
[(a,1), 
 (a,3),  
 (b,1),  
 (b,5),  
 (c,3), 
   ... ]
```

sequence Y contains days that tasks need

```
Y=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

How can I  get a sequence or something like  Z=Y-X .Days assigned to members

```
{  
a 2,4,5,6         
b 2,3,4,6         
c 1,2,4,5,6    
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please explain how you are geeting Z here.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good enough.Do you mean why I want to get Z?

Comment: I meant what does Z represent maybe an example would work.

Comment: `Z = Y - X` or `Z = X - Y`?  You've stated it both ways.  What is subtracting a list-of-tuples from a tuple (or subtracting a list-of-tuples from a tuple) supposed to _mean_, anyway?  Also, what does this have to do with [sqlalchemy]?

Comment: Thinking about this scenario:
A team leader assign tasks to team members. The tasks span from Monday to Saturday. The team members aren't free all the time. Member a is not free on 1,3 and b isn't on 1,5 and c isn't on 3…
The schedule of members is stored in database, and I will get it using SQLAlchemy.
session.query(name, free_date)
My englis is poor, can you understand me?

Comment: Sorry, the title is reverse.It should be "Z=Y-X"

Comment: Please [edit] your question --- correct the title, and add the details you posted in your most recent comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean some like:

```
In []:
r = {}
for m, n in X:
    r.setdefault(m, set()).add(n)
{k: [x for x in Y if x not in v] for k, v in r.items()}

Out[]:
{'a': [2, 4, 5, 6], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 6], 'c': [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method,

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

map(lambda x: d[x[0]].append(x[1]), X)

>> defaultdict(list, {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [1, 5], 'c': [3]})

f = {k: list(set(Y.get(k)).difference(set(d.get(k)))) for k in d.iterkeys()}

>> {'a': [2, 4, 5, 6], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 6], 'c': [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]}
```

Comment: Using a functional operation `map` for side-effects seems perverted.

Comment: it is a little perverted, I was being creative haha

Answer (score 0):

which you mean is deleting the numbers from tuple Y which appear in a,b and c? Then you can try this:

```
X = [('a',1),('a',3),('b',1),('b',5),('c',3)]
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

a = []
b = []
c = []

for tmp in X:
    if tmp[0] == 'a':
        a.append(tmp[1])
    elif tmp[0] == 'b':
        b.append(tmp[1])
    elif tmp[0] == 'c':
        c.append(tmp[1])

Z = {'a':[x for x in Y if x not in a], 
    'b':[x for x in Y if x not in b], 
    'c':[x for x in Y if x not in c]}
print Z
```